# Button click for navigation loads incorrect URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

In my Checkout.SelectAddress.cshtml page I have the following form:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost(Url.Action("SelectAddress", "Checkout", new { area = "Store" })))
    {  
    //extra code collecting information

    <li class="align right"><button type="submit">@T("Next")</button></li>
    }
```

I am using orchard cms 1.6 but I am having a problem with a navigation issue.
When the user clicks the above button they are directed to the URL:

```
http://localhost:30320/OrchardLocal/UMACS.Store/Checkout/Summary
```

I want to navigate to : `http://localhost:30320/OrchardLocal/`

i've tried replaing 'checkout' from the original form but having no joy. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you expect here. That form posts to a specific action in some module apparently named "Store". That action seems to then redirect to Summary. The only way you can make it redirect to something else is by changing its code.

Comment: yeah think I got it...thats for the reply B

Comment: Copying it as an answer then, so that you can grant it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That form posts to a specific action in some module apparently named "Store". That action seems to then redirect to Summary. The only way you can make it redirect to something else is by changing its code.